# Is there a database or like for Go-to function in visual studio code to make navigation fast over network

Tags: visual-studio-code

I develop system with over 6000 code files ( mostly in C++ ). I edit the files over the network remotely.

The finding `Ctrl+P` doesn't work efficiently and most of the times it can't find the files at all.

is there some way to force vs code to build a database of all files locally to make the `Ctrl+P` functionality faster.